# Ruby - How to use -r switch with ruby command line tool

Tags: ruby, command-line, switch-statement

I was trying to figure out how to work the command line switch -r.

My understanding is that the code is typed out as follows:

```
ruby -r*nameOfRequired*
```

I am finding that this is not the case. When I type out the above and press enter, the terminal expects an "end of input syntax" and does not continue.

What am I missing? Does there need to be a space in between the switch and the name of the required file?

Please and thank you!

---

**EDIT:**
I am currently reading "The Well Grounded Rubyist" by David A. Black, and I came up with this question while reading the section on command line switches.

Having said that, I created a "test.rb" file, containing:

```
puts Date.today
```

Then, in the terminal, I typed out:

```
ruby -r date
```

I thought this would 'require' the date module, and then enable me to run the "test.rb" file, using ruby test.rb (given that I am in the correct directory).

Instead, the terminal cursor moves to a newline, expecting more input. Let me know if I need to clarify anything else. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the exact command you are running and the file.  If you want to just run the file you do something like `ruby file.rb`.

Comment: Please provide the full error message.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: See above! Hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the `ruby` command does not record any state from one run to the next, so you need to tell it every thing that it needs to know whenever you run it.

Whenever you run it, you need to tell it the main program to run or else it will expect you to type that program on the standard input.  The `-r` does not specify the main program.

Try this:

```
ruby -rdate test.rb
```

**Update for 10-year anniversary of this answer:**  Of course, the more normal robust practice is to write `require 'date'` near the top of your `test.rb` file, so it always gets included no matter how the code gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

If you just type `ruby -r`*module*, then Ruby will load the module and wait for you to type the main program that requires that module.

If you just want to run the module and do nothing else, you can do do `ruby`*full-path-to-module* without the `-r`, or `ruby -r`*module* `-e exit`, or `ruby -r`*module* `</dev/null`, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

According to `ruby -h`:

> -rlibrary       require the library, before executing your script

Without giving your script file path, it read the script from stdin.

Try following (You can omit script file path when you give `-e command`):

```
ruby -r**nameOfRequired** -e ""
```